# how to divide sum of number by digit on number?

Tags: python

how to divide num of digit by digit number?

e.g : **4228** is true because **4+2+2+8=16** can divide by **4**, **2**, **8**

**3425** false because **3+4+2+5=14** can't divide by **3**, **4**, **2**, **5**

```
numbers = int(input('input number : '))
result = 0

# NUM of digit
while numbers > 0 :
    digit = numbers % 10
    result = result + digit
    numbers = numbers // 10

factors = result

#factors of "NUM of digit"
for factor_result in range(1,factors + 1) :
    if factors % factor_result == 0 :
        print(factor_result)
```

please help me;(

thank you a lot:))

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
num = 4220
res = [int(x) for x in str(num)]

can_devided = True
for r in res:
    if r == 0:
        continue
    if sum(res) % r != 0:
        can_devided = False
        

print (can_devided)
```

Comment: sorry if i input **3425** was true, however should false because **3+4+2+5=14** can't divided by **3**, **4**, **2**, **5**

Comment: sorry, my bad. i have updated the logic. please try it

Comment: maaf pak, gimana yaa menguecualikan pembagian 0, soalnya saya input 2020 malah 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/codingan/pengalihan isu/pengalihanisu.py", line 6, in <module>
    if sum(res) % r != 0:
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero`

Comment: sudah aku update lagi code, untuk menghandle 0 nya mas

Comment: okeee pak terima kasih banyak, akhirnya setelah seharian full:))

Answer (score 0):

From your description it sounds like you want a function like this

```
# determine if sum of integers comprising an integer is divisible by its part
def divisor_check(num):
    # check that input num is integer 
    if not isinstance(num,int):
       print('warning: input is not an integer')
       return False

    # break num into component integers by convert to string first
    stringafied_num = str(num)
    
    # split the string-afied num to get component integers
    components = [*stringafied_num]
    
    # evaluate the components to get integers back
    components = [eval(v) for v in components]
    
    # sum components
    total=sum(components)
    
    # try dividing total by each component 
    for c in components:
        if total%c != 0:
            return False
    return True
```

This function breaks up the input into its component integers, sums them, and computes the desired divisor check.

If you evaluate this function for your examples you get the desired results

`divisor_check(4228) --> True`

`divisor_check(3425) --> False`

Comment: note that ```eval()``` is a bit unsafe, as it [can execute arbitrary code objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval)

Comment: good call - added an integer check before the eval for input

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do it is to calculate the sum of the digits then check if the modulo is 0.

In python, we could parse the number to a str, then convert every digit (which is a single char) back to an int and create a list of these digits

```python
input_numbers = int(input('input number : '))

# parse the number to a str, then map each char back to an integer
# and create a list of int for each digit
numbers = list(map(int, str(input_numbers )))
```

Now, just use the built-in `sum()` method to get the result you wish. The next part is just a loop over every digit on the numbers list and check the module.

```python
result = sum(numbers)

is_divisible = True
for number in numbers:
  if number == 0 or result % int(number) != 0:
    is_divisible = False
print(is_divisible)
```

Comment: sorry, why if i input 2020 was ```input number : 2020
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/codingan/pengalihan isu/coba gess.py", line 10, in <module>
    if result % int(number) != 0:
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero ```?

Comment: @daylooo True, that happens because a division by zero is not possible. I updated my answer with a condition to this situation: when number == 0, the result is automatically not divisible.